# 2 Columns and 2 playlists issue

Tags: css, audio, playlist

Having a very frustrating issue here, I'm using 2 columns and an audio playlist plugin. Long story short, I need the audio players to appear side-by-side in the columns. Cannot figure this out :/

Here is the URL: http://www.airmanstudios.com/tests/

If I have to manually re-build the columns, what would be the best approach? tried using different column CSS/scripts to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#stacks_in_139_page8 .jwresp_col{
    width:100% !important;
}
#stacks_in_142_page8{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Seemed to do the job for me. That's some messy markup though and could be slimmed down if you wanted to modify some HTML.  Just put the above in your CSS though.

Comment: Didn't quite fix it yet, you just added this or replaced it with the current css selectors?

Comment: If you add that to your CSS it should do the job.  You can try adding important to the second two attributes also to see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your audio plugin isn't being very responsive, is it? Did you mess with the code to the audio plugin before you put it in?

Comment: No I did not. Anyway I could make it more responsive?